# What is the difference of app.UseAuthentication and app.UseAuthorization?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to write a middleware which executes between authentication and authorization.

I've registered that middleware between these the two authXYZ:

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseCustomMiddlerware();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

But I cannot get an authenticated user in my `CustomMiddlerware`.

When I deleted the `app.UseAuthentication()` statement then I found out that `AuthenticationHandler` still runs, and an authenticated user is available only after `app.UseAuthorization()`.

So, here are my questions:

1. Can I only use `app.UseAuthorization()` instead of using both `app.UseAuthentication()` and `app.UseAuthorization()`?
   1.1 What are the differences?
2. Are authentication and authorization triggered together?
   2.1 Is there any way to insert a middlerware between them?

Comment: The answer is dependent upon how you set up authentication. i.e. What does your `AddAuthentication` call look like in `ConfigureServices`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin The code uses build-in authentication. it looks like: var authBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(AuthenticationSchemes.ThirdPartyAuthenticationPolicy); authBuilder.AddJwtBearer(AuthenticationSchemes.ThirdPartyAuthenticationPolicy, options => {});

Comment: @StayReal Have seen [this call chain diagram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/index/_static/middleware-pipeline.svg?view=aspnetcore-3.1)? ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#middleware-order))

Comment: @PeterCsala, thanks. This diagram answers the second question. Do you have any comment on the first question? Using app.UseAuthorization() alone works the same as using both app.UseAuthentication() and app.UseAuthorization() at the same time.

Comment: @StayReal The `UseAuthentication`registers the `AuthenticationMiddleware`, whereas `UseAuthorization` registers the `AuthorizationMiddleware`. If you look at the source code of the latter one then you can see in the `Invoke` it calls the [Authenticate directly](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/AuthorizationMiddleware.cs#L58)

Answer (score 4):

Authentication and Authorization are two different things, but they also go hand in hand. Think of Authentication as letting someone into your home and Authorization as allowing your guests to do specific things once they’re inside (e.g. wear their shoes indoors, eat your food, etc). In other words, Authentication lets your web app’s users identify themselves to get access to your app and Authorization allows them to get access to specific features and functionality.

You can find more in [here](https://wakeupandcode.com/authentication-authorization-in-asp-net-core-3-1/)

Comment: This does not answer the questions asked above. He is not asking weather they go hand-in-hand. He asks without authentication also he is able to authorize the user. how & why?